# How to update applescript to open txt files in vim in iTerm3

Tags: vim, applescript, iterm2

For years I've been using the following AppleScript to open txt files in vim in iTerm2, but since iTerm 2.9.2 (aka iTerm3) it's broken. Could anyone advise how to update this AppleScript so it works again?

```
    on run {input, parameters}
    if (count of input) > 0 then
        tell application "System Events"
            set runs to false
            try
                set p to application process "iTerm"
                set runs to true
            end try
        end tell
        tell application "iTerm"
            activate
            if (count of terminals) = 0 then
                set t to (make new terminal)
            else    
                set t to current terminal
            end if
            tell t
                tell (make new session at the end of sessions)
                    exec command ("vim \"" & POSIX path of first item of input as text) & "\""
                end tell
                if not runs then
                    terminate first session
                end if
            end tell
        end tell
    end if
end run
```

I originally copied the script from http://earthwithsun.com/questions/283418/how-can-i-make-terminal-vim-my-default-editor-application-in-mac-os-x but I have no AppleScript experience whatsoever.

Any help most appreciated!
B

Comment: This code looks like it came from Automator, is that correct?  If not, how do you execute the script?

Comment: Yes, in Automator, save the AppleScript as Application, then associate that Application with txt files. Double click txt file in finder, it opens in vim in iTerm.

Comment: Are there any other Actions in this Automator workflow, or just the single Run AppleScript you have here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using @dusty's link, I recommend that you change the entire code section of your Run AppleScript Action to this:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "iTerm"
        activate
        if (count of windows) = 0 then
            set t to (create window with default profile)
        else
            set t to current window
        end if
        tell t
            tell current session
                write text ("vim \"" & POSIX path of first item of input as text) & "\""
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end run
```

It seems to work on my machine, but I never use vim, so I am not sure if this will give you precisely what you want.

Good luck,

Comment: does this need to be code signed? i tried exporting this as an app and running it and i see a no-op. in Console (the mac app) only hint i see is `3/25/16 12:26:36.000 PM kernel[0]: [90911|0] com.apple.CodeSi async. scan: #'/Applications/VI.app/Contents/Info.plist' act=0x00000002 rsn='ETYP1' ln='604'`

Comment: Works perfectly, Thanks @craig-smith

Answer (score 2):

The new Applescript syntax doesn't have `terminal` as a top-level object like before.  It has been changed to reflect more of the common pattern used throughout the OS for other scriptable applications: the top-level objects of the application are called windows, not terminals.

So the hierarchy is now something like this:

- the application containing one or more

  - windows containing one or more

    - tabs containing a

      - session

https://iterm2.com/applescript.html has been updated with examples of the new syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I adopted the code snippet of Craig Smith (great answer!) and tweaked it a little to open a new tab if there is already an open window. This way, you don't get any trouble if you have already something like vim opened in your iTerm. Also, this code changes the directory to the directory of the file to make NerdTREE and fuzzy finders like fzf.vim happy.

```
on run {input, parameters}
  set filename to POSIX path of input
  set cmd to "clear; pushd " & quote  & "$(dirname " & filename & ")" & quote  & " > /dev/null; nvim " & quote  & "$(basename " & filename & ")" & quote  & "; popd > /dev/null"

  tell application "iTerm"
    activate

    if (count of windows) = 0 then
      set t to (create window with default profile)
    else
      set t to current window
      tell t
        create tab with default profile
      end tell
    end if

    tell t
      tell current session
        write text cmd
      end tell
    end tell
  end tell
end run
```

Comment: Note that this crashes when all iTerm windows are minimized, because there is no `current window` then. Fixed with a simple `try` block.

Answer (score 1):

I took inspiration in the previous anwers and made a few extensions.
My solution accepts multiple input files (e.g. from a selection).
If there is an active window, the script searches for open vim sessions in any of the tabs and opens the files inside of that vim instance. If there are none, it creates a new iTerm tab or window.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set vimCommand to "nvim -p "
    tell application "iTerm"
        activate

        if (count of windows) = 0 then
            set w to (create window with default profile)
        else
            set w to current window

            try 
                # raises error when all windows are minimized
                tell w
                    # look for tab with open vim session
                    repeat with t in tabs
                        tell t
                            if name of current session contains "vim" then

                                # open files in current vim session
                                set esc to character id 27
                                tell current session
                                    write text (esc & esc & ":silent! tablast")
                                    repeat with filename in input
                                        set filePath to quoted form of POSIX path of filename
                                        write text (":execute 'tabedit '.fnameescape(" & filePath & ")")
                                    end repeat
                                    select
                                end tell
                                select
                                return
                            end if
                        end tell
                    end repeat

                    # no existing session
                    create tab with default profile
                end tell

            on error msg
                set w to (create window with default profile)
            end try
        end if

        # open in new tab or window
        tell w
            tell current session
                set launchPaths to ""
                repeat with filename in input
                    set filePath to quoted form of POSIX path of filename
                    set launchPaths to launchPaths & " " & filePath
                end repeat
                write text (vimCommand & launchPaths)
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end run
```

Comment: Returning after a few years, because I needed it again. This answer, which appeared several months after the original correct answer, is really great because it opens the file in a tab within vim if vim is already open in iTerm. If not, it opens iTerm and opens vim, as per original question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in Automator:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set vim_par to POSIX path of input
    set cmd to "/usr/local/bin/vim " & quote & vim_par & quote  
    tell application "iTerm"
        tell current window
            create tab with default profile command cmd
        end tell
    end tell
end run
```

Save as .app, and then open files via it -- probably, make that .app a default "Open with" app.